# How to get the total from X amount of prices in an array from a jQuery onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a small checkout system. I am basically taking information from an array and displaying the informaton. I am trying to do a live cart update. The user has options to pick more than one product and add it to the cart. I have simplified the code to highlight my issue. I can get the price no problem. Where I run into an issue is on multiple click events. So when they click €10 it adds in €10 fine. But I would like it to add in the next item on top of the €10 so it will give me €30. What is the best approach?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php 

$div_array = array('10','20','30');

foreach($div_array as $test)
{


 ?>
<div class = "container"><!-- The idea here is that this is going to be an image that a user will click on and get the below text once clicked  -->
<div class = "clickme"><h3><a href = "#"><?php echo $test; ?></a></h3> </div> <!-- This is the information I am trying to get -->
</div>
<?php


}
?>
<div class = "cost"></div>

<!-- Logic -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".container").click(function() {
var x = $(this).index();

var cost = $('.clickme').eq(x).text(); //Gets the cost of the product

$('.cost').html('<h1> This is the result €'+cost+'</h1>');//This is to display the live costs incrementing on each click not just replacing the text

});


}); 
</script>
```

Comment: The PHP isn't relevant to your question. Post the rendered HTML please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered your code, see the comments in the code for explanation.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="clickme">
    <h3><a href="#">10</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="clickme">
    <h3><a href="#">20</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="clickme">
    <h3><a href="#">30</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="cost"></div>

<script>
  /* define the total outside the function */
  var total = 0;
  
  $(function() {
    /* bind the function directly on the anchor: */
    $(".container .clickme a").click(function() {
      /* get the value */
      var cost = parseFloat( $(this).text() );
      /* add it to the total */
      total += cost;
      $('.cost').html('<h1> This is the result €' + total + '</h1>');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a total cost variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalcost = 0;
  $(".container").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).index();

    var cost = +$('.clickme').eq(x).text(); //Gets the cost of the product
    totalcost += cost;

    $('.cost').html('<h1> This is the result €' + totalcost + '</h1>'); // will print total cost now

  });
```